# Who is Daksha mentioned by Indra?

Tags: scripture, mahabharata

Consider the following statements of Indra from Mahabharata

> Assuming then the shape of a Brahmana, Sakra descended on the Earth and addressing the bird, said,--**O Suka, O best of birds, the
> grand-daughter (Suki) of Daksha has become blessed (by having thee as
> her offspring).**
>
> [[Section 5, Anusasanika Parva, The Mahabharata]](https://sacred-texts.com/hin/m13/m13a005.htm)

Who is Daksha in this context and what is his family tree?

Comment: This should be same Daksha prajapti..he was Shuki's maternal grand father..but Daksha appointment all his daughters as putrika as he didn't have son so may be he can be called Shuki's grandfather also..

Comment: @YDS Do you mean the father of Sati?

Comment: Yes.... @hanugm

Answer (score 2):

Daksha Prajapati's daughter Taamra was married to Kashyapa. Shuki was name of one of the daughters of Taamra. Śukī gave birth to parrots.

As Indra was talking to a "Suka" i.e. parrot whose origin is from Daksha > Taamra > Śukī, he referred same Daksha Prajapati.

Daksha was son of Lord Brahma in Svaymbhu Manvanra. Later in Vaivaswata Manvantra (or at the end of Chakshusa Manvantra), he incarnated as son of Prachetas (10 collective sons of Prācīnabarhis in King Prathu's lineage) and in this incarnation also his name was Daksha and he became Prajapati too.

Reference: [Shiva Purana: Umā-Saṃhitā: Chapter 30](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/shiva-purana-english/d/doc226590.html) to Chapter 32.